# error404 on 2nd booking event page

Tags: wordpress, civievent

using WP 5.4.2 -  PHP 7.2 - CiviCRM 5.27.3.
I have issue with Permalink (I dont know if it is the root cause) but I can create a article using the CiviCRM button  to add the CiviCRM event form. On the website, the 1st page form is available and can be filled until the user press the "next" button that display error404 screen on the next page -

Answer (score 3):

I expect this is due to changes made to accommodate WP URL changes.   If the URL has `civiwp` in it (and it should) Then I would:

- make sure that the base page is set - go to https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1
- Review the Base Page setting and value, it cannot be blank
- Make sure there is a published page that matches the one in that page
- If there is no value there, add one, `civicrm` is the default and then create a WP page with that slug
- Make sure the page is public and visiuble to all
- Once you've done that (or confirmed the base page exists) Visit this page https://example.org/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
- Confirm that your permalinkls are set to anything EXCEPT `Plain`
- If it is set to Plain change to one of the other options and save
- If it is not set to plain, you can exit the page

Then retry the form.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for answering,

- The URL is already set to : civicrm (it was the default value)
- I cannot reach any page at http://example.org/civicrm/ (*)
  **- The options permalink is set to "simple in french" = http://migrationccb.esy.es/?p=123**
- I set the new value at "Date et titre" =
  http://migrationccb.esy.es/2020/08/03/exemple-article/
- I create a new public event, the Permalink = /event/info/?reset=1&id=3

=> I cannot use the Permalink but if I create a Post I succesd to pass the 3 step to book the event as public-user

Fab !
Thank you for ths help.

*nota : up to now I use http I shall later activate SSL certificate*