# WordPress 5.27 membership renewals failing

Tags: wordpress, civimember, error

I'm on latest WordPress, with Civi 5.27.4

Membership renewals fail both with a URL created with smarty sent in an email (which has previously worked), and attempting to renew a logged-in admin. The failure is at the same point: the final confirmation screen. Instead of loading the confirmation screen users get an error pag with a broken link: `https://example.com/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact`

**Things I have tried**

1. upgraded to latest 5.27.x
2. flushed caches and rebuilt urls
3. implemented CLEANURLS (I think)
4. Turned off Stripe Extension
5. Checked for any corrupt database tables

None of this has solved the problem. Any advice gratefully received, as you can imagine this is a pretty significant problem.

Comment: can you check what is set in CMS Database Integration? Did you follow everything from https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/37274/155

Comment: yes @PradeepNayak I've checked everything listed there. To be clear, most of the pages with Civi URLs work, but not the final confirmation page for renewals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is actually a bug in the OpenStreetMap geocoding extension. A fix is coming.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this url `https://example.com/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact`  It appears the base page is missing.

Can you look at :

- make sure that the base page is set - go to https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1
- Review the Base Page setting and value, it cannot be blank
- Make sure there is a published page that matches the one in that page
- If there is no value there, add one, civicrm is the default and then create a WP page with that slug
- Make sure the page is public and visible to all
- Once you've done that (or confirmed the base page exists) Visit this page https://example.org/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
- Confirm that your permalinkls are set to anything EXCEPT Plain
- If it is set to Plain change to one of the other options and save
- If it is not set to plain, you can exit the page
- Flush CiviCRM Caches go to https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2FupdateConfigBackend&reset=1  and click cleanup caches

After all that is complete, try a test membership renewal.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Per the comment above I did try all of that. However you're right about the base URL not appearing. It's definitely set (and none of these settings have changed for several years) so I'm not sure what's going on. Presumably it's related to the 5.26/5.27 upgrade.

Comment: I'd try re-saving the base page settings, that should update the setting in the DB.